# Where can I find information on Rabbi Yaacov Wazana

Tags: biography

In a lecture I attended some years ago mention was made of a Rabbi Yaacov Wazana, who practiced some sort of Jewish healing in Morocco. I would like to know where I can find biographical information on this person and/or any of his writings.

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=V4H6DPLwFC0C&dq=Life+and+Death+of+Rabbi+Yaakov+Wazana&source=gbs_navlinks_s

Answer (score 3):

I know this is very old post but
what kind of info are you looking for?
any chance you speak Hebrew?
that rabbi died in my grandfathers house back in morocco around 60-70 years ago (if I'm not miscounting..),
I've heard many stories from my older uncles who met him when they were kids, my father and uncles told me about magical stuff he used to do healing,transforming water (i kid you not) he once changed a sack of water into "Arak",he had the ability to communicate with souls and demons,
before passing away he removed a curse from my grandparents that made their baby's die (more than 6 died before reaching 1 year old) and sacrificed his soul so that my father, some of my uncles, and aunts may live. my grandfather took on himself to do a the Jewish memorial of ya'acov wazana every year, after my grandfather passed away my uncle took it on himself and keeping it going every year. (my grandfather moved to Israel after marrying and i know that some of ya'acov wazana's family did too. but ya'acov and my great grandfather are buried in the same graveyard in Agouim in the Atlas Mountains, morocco.

Comment: thank you for sharing, very fascinating

Answer (score 2):

A simple google search yielded:

- [This](http://courses.umass.edu/juda373/outlines/documents/Daryn.pdf)
- [This](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF00047041#page-1)
- and [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=V4H6DPLwFC0C&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=Rabbi%20Yaacov%20Wazana%20morocco&source=bl&ots=dUcHjTSiLd&sig=BW6e0-Mv0LEdCP8DXW_JL7s3CcQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=AwOWVeuNB4Pq-QHDvJa4Aw&ved=0CFIQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Rabbi%20Yaacov%20Wazana%20morocco&f=false)
- This in [Hebrew](http://www.masa.co.il/article/94/%D7%A8%D7%91%D7%99-%D7%99%D7%A2%D7%A7%D7%91-%D7%95%D7%96%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%94:-%D7%94%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA-%D7%A2%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%93%D7%99%D7%9D/)
- and [this](http://www.literatura.co.il/website/index.asp?id=27128) in Hebrew

Comment: When I click the first link I get the following error message: "You don't have permission to access /juda373/outlines/documents/Daryn.pdf on this server."

Comment: @Eliyahu https://www.jstor.org/stable/3773787

Answer (score -1):

I read about your family in Yoram's Bilu book about Yaakov Vazana who is a family member of me. I search about his life and would love to speake with you about it
you can contact me at elad@havayati.co.il
Blessings,
Elad